# Jquery / Bootstrap 3 Slider (Moving individual items)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[JSFiddle of Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/1jyvygk1/)

I have a slider that i picked off another post which had a very similar question. The aim of the slider was to have multiple elements on screen at once, rather than one. These would then move one by one off screen, being replaced by another.

**Example**

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6  **>>>** 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 **>>>** 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8

Currently, the slider moves the entire row at once, rather than just sliding one to the right / left. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title> Spotlight Productions  </title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon2.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,500,800,700,600,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider.js"></script>
    <link href = "css/styles.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body style = "background-color: green">        
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f566f5/333&amp;text=5" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f477f4/fff&amp;text=6" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=7" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="col-sm-2"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/fcfcfc/333&amp;text=8" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/** Client Slider **/

.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -16%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  16%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}

.col-sm-2 {width: 16%;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
  })

  $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
      next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i=0;i<4;i++) {
      next=next.next();
      if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }

      next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You started your CSS the right way but missed some "100%" appearances. So everywhere bootstrap uses a "100%" positioning or transformation you just replace it with your "16%":

```
/** Client Slider **/
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
.col-sm-2 {width: 16%;}

@media all and (transform-3d), (-webkit-transform-3d) {
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.next,
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(16%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(16%, 0, 0);
  }
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-16%, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-16%, 0, 0);
  }
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.next.left,
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.prev.right,
  #myCarousel .carousel-inner > .item.active {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}

#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .active {
  left: 0;
}

#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .next {
  left: 16%;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .prev {
  left: -16%;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .next.left,
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .prev.right {
  left: 0;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .active.left {
  left: -16%;
}
#myCarousel .carousel-inner > .active.right {
  left: 16%;
}
```

The updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1jyvygk1/2/)

Comment: This works but is there any way to get rid of the lagging that happens after each transition? It feels like it's correcting the image width after each transition.

Comment: edit: works fine, must just be jfiddle. Thanks so much